# Why macroexpansion doesn't expand nested forms in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, macros

I don't understand how to get the full macro expansion.

With this code

```
(when true (when true true))
```

I would like to get the full macro expansion

```
(if true (do (if true (do true)))
```

But I can't

I understand `macroexpansion-1` will resolve the first level of expansion :

```
(macroexpand-1 '(when true (when true true)))

(if true (do (when true true)))
```

But why when I call again `macroexpand-1` (that's what should do `macroexpand`) :

```
(macroexpand-1 '(if true (do (when true true))))
```

I got the exact same result ?

```
(if true (do (when true true)))
```

I was expecting a full macro expansion.

Does macro expansion only works with top level forms ?

I'm aware of an `expand-all` function in the `clojure.walk` namespace, so I
suppose `macroexpand` doesn't work on nested structures. Am I right ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right.

See also https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand

Where it states :

> Note neither macroexpand-1 nor macroexpand expand macros in subforms.

And indeed macroexpand-all does the recursive expansion :

```
> (clojure.walk/macroexpand-all '(when true (when true true))) 
(if true (do (if true (do true))))
```

See also https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/macroexpand-all

where it states :

> Recursively performs all possible macroexpansions in form.

Your example

```
(macroexpand-1 '(if true (do (when true true))))
```

might confuse you, but it does as the docs tell :

> (macroexpand-1 form) If form represents a macro form, returns its
>   expansion, else returns form.

So since 'if' is not  a macro, it just returns if, without going into subforms...